# Как в Android подгрузить сторонние динамические библиотеки?

Tags: android, linux, библиотеки

Как в Android подгрузить сторонние динамические библиотеки `.so`? `/lib/ld.so.conf` отсутствует в Android, есть `/lib/ld.config.txt` со своим форматом, и `/linkerconfig` в Android 11.